# staruml "combined fragment" layout

Tags: uml, staruml

Am facing a bit of trouble getting the 'combined fragment' to sit above an activation (in a sequence diagram).

On adding a 'combined fragment' (loop/alt/opt etc) to a section of the sequence diagram, the label and the guard condition appear 'under' the activation block and hence is obscured.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is 'how it works right now'.. until this is fixed (which I doubt, as the development has been abandoned) I will have to live with this.