# How to create a abstract method in staruml 5

Tags: uml, abstract-methods, staruml

does anybody know how to create an abstract method in staruml 5.0?
The UML standard says that such a method should be italic, but it seems that is not possible in staruml 5.0 for a single method?
please help me :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As depicted in the attached, you just have to select your method on the "model explorer" and then set it as "IsAbstract" on the  properties tab.
I just would to know why you use this modeler which have not been release since 2005?
Regards,
EBR

[image: abstract method]

Comment: Ah, thank you very much. I used this modeler because I looked for many modeler and the most of them seems to be ....^^ StarUML isn't the best tool for that stuff I think, but it's not so complicated like other programs I had tested. Rather, I want to use Visual Paradigm Community Edition, but I do not really know if this edition (because of the license) is allowed to use for education purposes (like an exam).

Comment: I personally do not like dead software because if you get stuck it is generally permanent, I like living software :-)). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757282/staruml-combined-fragment-layout?rq=1 
My personal modeler choice is Modelio (http://www.modelio.org/) ...