# StarUML - cannot indicate abstract operations (italics) in abstract class

Tags: class, diagram, staruml

When I set the class as abstract, only its name is displayed in italics. But to be correct from UML point of view, I need the operations to be in italics too. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a abstract method in staruml 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497197/how-to-create-a-abstract-method-in-staruml-5)

Answer (score 3):

You have to go into the model explorer and set the "isAbstract" property for the operation you want.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18497197/how-to-create-a-abstract-method-in-staruml-5) for a walkthrough on how to do it.